# Can one get some partial ammo compatibility or tooling simplification by developing a few weapons of caliber ~80mm together?

Tags: weapons, engineering, modern

For a few weapons there is something akin to sweet spot around caliber ~80mm:

- Carl Gustaf 8.4 cm recoilless rifle (rifled)
- 81 mm mortar (smoothbore)
- FIM-92 Stinger (72 mm) / 9K38 Igla (72 mm) (obviously smoothbore)
- OTO Melara 76 mm (naval gun) / Denel GT4 76mm 62-calibre rifled gun (South African Rooikat) (rifled)
- 81 mm smoke grenade discharger installed on tanks

**Assuming that one develops similar weapon system to above mentioned from scratch with no legacy issues, is there any potential for developing those weapons in manner that would make some ammo partially compatible or tooling a bit easier?**

(I was wondering about situation when if desperate one could load ammo from different weapon type and technically be able to fire some shots like loading mortar shell to a recoilless rifle and fire that on very short range. Or some recoilless shells being able to be used for artillery though suffering from having shape optimized for subsonic flight. Or maybe one could at least benefit from the same tooling able to produce tubes of the same diameter easier? Or reusing tolling would actually make sense with different diameter based on being riffled/smoothbore?)

Comment: I assume you are asking: does this make sense in a modern military world? Would an army commission something like this circa 2023? Fot that you'd need specialist knowledge, maybe this question is better off in the engineering community? From a worldbuilding perspective I don't really see any obstacles to saying that "this is how my story works"

Answer (score 3):

A little bit of tooling simplification. All five of the weapons you mention fire completely different ammunition, and you can neither put a Stinger into a light naval gun nor fire a mortar bomb from a recoilless rifle, even if they were all the same diameter. You probably won't even mount the same fuse, and if you can do that it won't depend on the outer diameter of the projectile. A mortar barrel is completely different from a cannon barrel, that's why mortars are so light and portable.

Possibly there are benefits for some smart ordnance. Say [RAAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Anti-Armor_Mine_System) variant of the 80mm cannon round holds five anti-armor mines, the mortar holds four, and a recoilless rifle holds two. Or [cluster bomb ammunition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-purpose_improved_conventional_munition), but there the problem would be that an artillery shell needs to be more sturdy than a mortar round, with stronger walls to stand the greater stress of firing. So it might well have a smaller interior diameter.

But you can probably get some benefits where it comes to the tools to build the weapons and ammunition, and especially the tools to build the tools. Say you need specially hardened 80mm drill bit to replace parts both of the mortar production line and the cannon production line.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible?

*Sort of*

What immediately sprung to mind was [The MGM-51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MGM-51_Shillelagh) which tried to combine an Artillery Gun with a Missile Gun.

TL;DR - it didn't really work that well. I think there are some Soviet-era designs that still use this concept.

The Main issue you have is that each munition has a different desired down-range effect. A Smoke Launcher for example is mainly concerned with obscuring yourself - things like Range and Time-in-flight aren't a consideration. Whereas with an Anti-Tank munition (like the CG) the longer it takes the rocket to get to the target, the more time the target has to react, take cover and get one his buddies to send a 120mm care package your way.

But let's put our big-brains on for a moment.

Assume we standardize all this class of projectiles to 80 mm - easy enough to do.
We could also standardize the length of the projectile - accepting that this will decrease efficiency for some applications and be over-kill for others, our hope is that the simplified logistics will make up for this.

We settle on a standard set of warhead types - High Explosive, Armor Piercing, Smoke, White Phosphorous, Frag, Incendiary etc.

Then you could have interchangeable Cases/Rocket motors/Mortar fins etc.

In *theory* this could work, in practice however, if you have to machine a different Case, Rocket motor etc. you may as well just machine up the whole thing.

Limiting say an Anti-Aircraft rocket by it's length because you need a specific length for firing from a Naval gun doesn't make a lot of sense.

There comes a point that in order to standardize, you have to compromise too much.